Gazebo Fortress `gz-sim-joint-state-publisher-system` isn't publishing any messages to /joint_states topic in ROS2
I've been trying to set up Gazebo Fortress for ROS2 Humble, and I'm trying to do it without ROS2 Control. I set everything up to publish my joint states from Gazebo, and it's creating the joint_states topic, but when I ros2 topic echo /joint_states there are no messages? This is really bothering me and I'm not sure what to do next. I'd appreciate answers to solve my problem without using ros2 control. You can find the github repo for my project HERE, and my xacro files are in src/roomba_891_py/description
Thanks!
